# Get same characters from 2 lists in right order - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have two lists and I need to print matching characters to string in order of characters in list 2. If there is no match, i need to print "-" instead of that character. Final string should have same length of chars as list 2

Example 1 :

```
list 1 = ["r", "w", "d"]
list 2 = ["w", "o", "r", "d"]
```

Expected output = W - R D

Example 2:

```
list 1 = ["r"]
list 2 = ["w", "o", "r", "d"]
```

Expected output = - - R -

Comment: You can't leave out a list element in Pythong. `,,` is invalid.

Comment: Use `itertools.zip_longest()` to loop over the two lists in parallel. You can then compare each corresponding element. If they're equal, output the character, otherwise output `-`.

Comment: Why is the final result `- - R -`? The `r` in list 1 is in the wrong place.

Comment: if order doesn't matter, just use `if current_character_of_list_2 in list_1:` to tell if the character matches or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to check if the character in actual word (`list2`) is present in the `list1` or not so:

```
list1 = ["r", "w", "d"]
list2 = ["w", "o", "r", "d"]
print(' '.join([i.upper() if i in list1 else '-' for i in list2]))
```

**Output:**

```
W - R D
```

---

You can optionally create a set from list1 for faster lookup in case the word lengths are huge.

```
given_words = set(list1)
print(' '.join([i.upper() if i in given_words else '-' for i in list2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a list comprehension making sure you change case to upper and then print by unpacking the list

```
list_1 = ["r", "w", "d"]
list_2 = ["w", "o", "r", "d"]
print(*[e.upper() if e in list_1 else '-' for e in list_2])
```

**Output:**

```
W - R D
```

Optionally, unpack a generator:

```
print(*(e.upper() if e in list_1 else '-' for e in list_2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one solution:

```
list1 = ["r"]
list2 = ["w", "o", "r", "d"]

for c in list2:
    if c in list1: print(c.upper(), end=' ')
    else: print('-', end=' ')


> Output:
> - - R -
```